# bot.procces_commands(message) Ошибка в discord.py

Tags: discord.py

В моем боте в дискорд есть ивент on_message, в котором идет проверка на присутствие пользователя в бд, и в конце прописано: `bot.process_commands(message)`, на это дает ошибку:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.process_commands' was never awaited bot.process_commands(message) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Вот полный код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?", (message.author.id,)).fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ({message.author.id}, 100, 'Нету', 0, 0)")
        conn.commit()
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ({message.guild.id}, {message.author.id}, '')")


    bot.process_commands(message)
```

Как исправить?

Comment: В тексте ошибки написано, что асинхронная вызывается не  асинхронно. Добавьте `await` перед `process_commands`

Comment: Спасибо, а то я бы долго не понимал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. вы используете `process_commands()` в ассинхронной функции вам нужно использовать `await`

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```